# error.CannotStartupOSGIPlatform issue when running birt

Tags: gwt, birt

I'm in the midst of implementing Birt 4.6.0 into my gwt application. Unfortunately whenever I run a specific section of the program, I get the following error:

> org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.BirtException:
>   error.CannotStartupOSGIPlatform   at
>   org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.startup(Platform.java:81)

I've done some searching and one thread mentioned a [permissions error](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/218598/) but I am not sure what that entails. What does this mean?

**EDIT** Just read another article that suggests that it may be an issue with my classpath but I already added all the jar files from ReportEngine/lib to my buildpath. Anyone know what jar files I am supposed to include?

the offending code:

```
public static synchronized IReportEngine getBirtEngine(ServletContext sc) {
    if (birtEngine == null) {
        EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
        java.util.HashMap map = config.getAppContext();;
        map.put(EngineConstants.APPCONTEXT_CLASSLOADER_KEY, SegnalazioniDbManager.class.getClassLoader()); 
        config.setAppContext(map);
        IPlatformContext context = new PlatformServletContext(sc);
        config.setPlatformContext(context);


        try {
            Platform.startup(config); //problem begins here
            .....
            }


  [1]: http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/20933-errorcannotstartuposgiplatform/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is indeed a permission error.

The relevant file is:

> WEB-INF/platform/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock

You need to give access to the Birt user.